# Preserve form data when transition through pages Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a register form page, and some links on it, to terms and conditions page. When I click on this terms and conditions link, it opens this other page and when I go back to register page the data I put on the form it is not longer there.
My register route looks like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

    model() {
         return this.store.createRecord('post');
    },
    actions:{
        createPost(post){
            post.save().then(function(){
                 //on success
            },function(message){
                 //on error
            });
        }

    }
});
```

How can I preserve the data when I go back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create the record in a singleton, which will be either a controller or service in Ember's case, and then return that record in your model hook. Have a look at this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/6379d74f7b9bf2674bbc0dbc8a155aa0?openFiles=services.persistance-helper.js%2C&route=%2Fpost) for a working example. A quick example of the code you'll need:

```
//services/persistance-helper.js
export default Ember.Service.extend({

  store: Ember.inject.service(),

  rememberRecord(type, record){
    this.set(type,record)
  },

  retrieveRecord(type){
    const record = this.get(type)
    console.log('record:',record)
    if(record){
      return record
    }else{
      return this.get('store').createRecord(type)
    }
  },

  removeRecord(type){
    this.set(type,null)
  }
})
```

> 

```
//routes/post.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({

  persistanceHelper: Ember.inject.service(),

  model(){
    return this.get('persistanceHelper').retrieveRecord('post')
  },

  actions:{

    willTransition(){
      console.log()
      if(this.currentModel.get('dirtyType') === 'created'){
        this.get('persistanceHelper').rememberRecord('post',this.currentModel)
      }else{
        console.log('else:',this.currentModel.get('dirtyType'))
        console.log('record was saved ?')
      }
    },

    save(){
      this.currentModel.save().then((record)=>{
            this.get('persistanceHelper').removeRecord('post')
      })
    }
  }

})
```

I think the code is descriptive enough to not add a longer explanation :)